# Find Differential Coefficients using function rule (Check my work)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Can someone tell me if my working out are correct please.

Quesion:

$$ y = {\sqrt 3x^2 + 4x - 1} $$

My calculations:

$$ y = {\sqrt 3x^2 + 4x}= ( 3x^2 + 4x)^1/2 $$

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac {1}{2} ( 3x^2 + 4x)^1/2$$

$$^1 (6x + 4) = 1/2 (3x^2 + 4x) -1/2(6x + 4)$$

$$ \frac {dy}{dx} = \frac {6x + 4}{2 \sqrt 3x^2 + 4x} $$

Is this correct?

If not where have i gone wrong?

Comment: First, you write $y = \sqrt 3 x^2 + 4x - 1$,then later you forget the $-1$,  then suddenly divide by $2$ (is that a MathJax typing error?), no please sort it out (actually, hang on, I think you've made the MathJax error everywhere : probably what you meant was $y = \left(\sqrt{3x^2 + 4x}\right)$,  in which case the answer is correct)

Comment: Yes was suppose to be square root of everything. Sorry just typed mathjax wrong. So it is correct with square root of everything?

Comment: It is correct. Having said that, do correct the question also! Write an answer yourself (copy your attempt into an answer, maybe) and cloe the question.

Comment: If you meant $y = \sqrt{3x^2 + 4x - 1}$, type `$y = \sqrt{3x^2 + 4x - 1}$`.  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) may be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The square root sign applies only to $3$ and so $\frac {dy} {dx} =\sqrt 3(2x)+4=2 \sqrt 3x+4$.

If the square root sign applies to the entire expression then  your answer has just one mistake. You should have $\sqrt {3x^{2}+4x-1}$ in the denominator.

Comment: Was mean to square root everything. Not just the 3.